# How do I make a relatively large NFA in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

the machine I'm trying to build will have 15 states and when I compile the states start to run off the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\usepackage{float}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\tikzset{
    ->, % makes the edges directed
    %>=stealth’, % makes the arrow heads bold
    node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ node
    initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    1.19 a
    %\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial](1) {};
        \node[state, right of=1](2){};
        \node[state, above right of=2](3){};
        \node[state, right of=3](4) {};
        \node[state, below right of=2](5){};
        \node[state, right of=5](6){};
        \node[state, below right of=4](7){};
        \node[state,right of=7](8){};
        \node[state,right of=8](9){};
        \node[state,right of=9](10){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: (i) in your code fragment is only 10 states., (ii) using  `article` document class and TikZ library `automata` your image is well inside text area (since nodes are placed very close to each other). What exactly is your problem? Please extend code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have added the packages. I stopped coding  after ten states because for me they started running off the page after six.

Comment: You are using a deprecated way of positioning nodes. If you load and use the positioning library things will get way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already load `positioning` so you may want to use it. "Using it" means instead of `right of=` say `right=of` or `right=<distance> of`, and similarly for `above`, `below` and `left`. Making the graph smaller is as simple as setting a not too large `node distance`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\tikzset{
    ->, % makes the edges directed
    %>=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
    node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
    initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2em]
        \node[state, initial](1) {};
        \node[state, right=of 1](2){};
        \node[state, above right=of 2](3){};
        \node[state, right=of 3](4) {};
        \node[state, below right=of 2](5){};
        \node[state, right=of 5](6){};
        \node[state, below right=of 4](7){};
        \node[state,right=of 7](8){};
        \node[state,right=of 8](9){};
        \node[state,right=of 9](10){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please also consider not using the `float` package, and using `arrows.meta` instead of `arrows`.

Comment: What if I want to go 2 spaces down. Like for instance if I want to place a node 2 spaces below the 7th node from the left in the above diagram?

Comment: @JohnHendrickson `node distance` accepts two arguments. You seem to want `node distance=4em and 2em` (or the other way around).

Comment: What if I need to bend far, like from 1 to 7 in the diagram above?

Comment: @JohnHendrickson `\draw (1) to[out=50,in=90,looseness=1.2] (7);`. You may need to adjust the `in` and `out` angles and/or the looseness. But please one question at a time. You may ultimately want to do something like graph drawing.

Comment: cat, can you please point me towards some resources for graph drawing?

Comment: @JohnHendrickson see chapter **IV Graph Drawing** on pp. 415 of pgfmanual v3.1.5.